# What is better for using a custom font for my website?

Tags: html, css, performance, fonts, cdn

I'm using a font called "**DejaVu Sans**" that does not exist in google fonts

```
body{
    font-family:'DejaVu Sans' , tahoma;
}
```

I uploaded the font with different extensions to my website but it takes time to execute on the text on my website, I think it waits for the whole website to load first.

Is it better to upload the font files to a CDN or a files cloud and then use it on my website, or there is a better way?

Comment: The way that you're currently using, it's just loading the font from your local machine - anyone who hasn't that font installed on their system will just see a fallback font.

Comment: Also note that you have to stick to the font licence (I'm not informed what licence DejaVu Sans is distributed under) - you can't just convert and/or use any font you like as a webfont or you might have to face legal consequences.

Comment: @Connum , I uploaded the font to my website files I forgot to add : `@font-face {
    font-family: 'DejaVu Sans';
 src: url(../fonts/DejaVuSans.eot);
        src: url(../fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf)  format("truetype"), 
             url(../fonts/DejaVuSans.woff) format("woff");
}`

Answer (score 1):

you should use font face like this :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

then you can use the font wherever you want

Answer (score 1):

The font load time depends on the font file size. You can use font face kit provided by font-squirrel : https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/dejavu-sans

To improve loading time you can wisely choose the required font formats to bind with your website font face.

To get more information about loading time you can refer below link, which will helps a lot.
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/the-font-face-rule-revisited-and-useful-tricks/

Answer (score 0):

use `@font-face` instead.

Upload your .ttf files and convert them to .woff, .woof2 etc that is needed for font face.

Here is the link for standard `@font-face` example : 
[@font-face](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)

Use online converter here: [webfont converter](https://transfonter.org/)